Boolean Algebra Confusion

So Im going through the nand2tetris course on my own for fun, and I am at the half adder/adder portion. The half adder was pretty easy just based on the truth table, but the full adder im having more difficulty with simplifying the truth table.
The above picture I understand (outside of the rule for making a "XOR" in boolean algebra) but the 2nd to last expression I don't understand how the 2nd to last expression turns into
S=AxorBxorCin
Can someone explain what rules they are using because I am not understanding it?

They're using the definition of xor, i.e.
$$X \oplus Y = \overline{X}\cdot Y + X\cdot\overline{Y}$$
This is the same thing that was applied when going from the second line to the third line of the derivation in your question, to go from \$\overline{B}\cdot{C_{in}} + {B}\cdot\overline{C_{in}}\$ to \${B}\oplus{C_{in}}\$.
In this case, the formula is applied by substituting \$A\$ for \$X\$ and the entire expression \${B}\oplus{C_{in}}\$ for \$Y\$.
Really, they get \$A\oplus(B\oplus C_{in})\$, but xor (as defined in this case) is commutative and associative so the order and parentheses don't matter.

Ok that makes sense. However how exactly does B'Cin' + BCin become NOT(BxorCin). Is it using the associative law to make it B'Cin+BCin' but wouldn't that just be BxorCin?

Also I guess a side question: is boolean algebra just something that takes a lot of practice. Because Im having a hard time I guess "seeing" where rules should apply and shouldn't

@msmith1114 That can come either from the definition of XNOR, a truth table analysis, an exhaustive listing of all the things that make XNOR true, or from a more thorough rearrangement that takes a few steps. Definition (and intuition once you see the definition enough times) is probably the easiest path for it.
